# SNES Limitations: Number of stored Graphics?

Tags: sprites, storage

There are plenty of resources that tell you how many sprites can appear on a screen for a SNES game and how many per scanline. There is even answers for the number of tilemaps.

But when I ask the question "How many texture pages could a SNES store on a cartridge? And what size approx.?", that is when there is silence. I appreciate there were no such thing as texture pages back then (it was just a way to explain the question) but surely someone must how many tiles and sprites a SNES cartridge could store on a game?

Any documents/articles that can help me is highly appreciated. Perhaps I missed something while looking on google.

Comment: I think the only limit was the size of the ROM on the cartridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Game_cartridge)

> The largest games released (Tales of Phantasia and Star Ocean) contain
>   48 Mbit of ROM data

That's 6MBytes.

The smallest tile/sprite you could easily store is a 8x8 1bpp tile, giving you (6*1024*1024/8) 786,432 tiles without any space for code and other data.
**196,608 tiles for 8x8 4bpp** and 262,144 tiles for 8x8 3bpp.

That is without using compression or custom ROM controller. Using a ROM banking controller there is no theoretical limit.

Comment: You speak a lot about bpp. Could you tell me what that does and how it effects the number of tiles? And could explain the calculations you used to get the number of tiles?

Comment: Oh wait I found it. So the bpp is based on the number of colours. In that case I just want to know how you calculate the number of tiles? :)

Comment: The calculation steps are shown in the answer: take the total memory (6 MB), convert it to bytes (*1024*1024), and divide by the number of bytes in a single tile (in this example, 8x8x1bpp = 64 bits = 8 bytes)